# Ruby on Rails Custom Domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, dns

I am writing a web app which works on subdomains. I would also like to add custom domains so users can create a CNAME so their domain (`hello.com`) goes to their subdomain (`123.hellothere.com`).

How would I go about going this with Ruby on Rails?

I already have subdomains working fine on my app, I just seem to be having problems with adding custom domains.

I have `subdomain` and `custom_domain` in the database relating to the users blog.

I have tried following this tutorial - http://glacialis.postmodo.com/posts/cname-and-subdomain-routing-in-rails - with no luck.

*EDIT*

`subdomain` and `custom_domain` are attached to the Blog model. For the subdomains I used this tutorial at [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you have your subdomains set up but you should have some code which looks like this somewhere:

```
def current_account
  Account.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain) || Account.find_by_custom_domain(request.host)
end
```

This code is just a proof of concept. You should make sure that you a) protect against people stealing each others domains (uniqueness check on the custom_domain parameter) and b) make sure that they don't enter your domain into the custom_domain field allowing them to have multiple "local" domains.

Edit: you should also make sure that, if the `current account` method is defined on a controller, that you memoize it with a `@current_account ||=` to avoid un-necessary calls to the database.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind if you are using SSL is that you will need a wildcard certificate which is usually a bit more expensive. Otherwise, you will run into issues with your clients getting an invalid certificate because the subdomain doesn't match.